# How to show $G_{n}^{\perp}=nX$?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a diagonalizable algebraic group, and $G_{n}$ denotes the subgroup of elements of order dividing $n$. Assuming $k$ is algebraically closed and has characteristic $p$ and $p$ does not divide $n$. Here $H^{\perp}$ denotes elements in $X(G)$ such that $X(h)=1,\forall h\in H$. I want to show:

1) $G_{n}^{\perp}=nX$

2) The subgroup of elements of finite order is dense in $G$.

I have some ideas but both questions remained unsolved. If I use the structure theorem on $G$, this reduces to the case $G=G_{m}$ or $G=\bf Z_{n_{j}}$ with $n_{j}\in \bf Z,gcd(n_{j},p)=1$. It is trivial that for any $\chi\in nX$, $\chi(G_{n})=1$. But it is not clear to me how to show if $\chi(g)=1,\forall g\in G_{n}$, then $\chi=nX$.

Similarly I do not really know how to solve the second problem, where the subgroup of finite order has infinite cardinality, but this alone does not help me to assert it is dense in $G$.

Comment: Here are some thoughts (I will not call them hints, as I am not certain if they lead in the completely correct direction): In the case of $G = \mathbb{G}_m$ we know that $X(G)$ consists of precisely the morphisms of the form $g\mapsto g^k$ for some integer $k$, and if $g^k = 1$ for all $g\in G_n$ then we must have $k$ divisible by $n$ (remember that $k$ is algebraically closed so we do have elements of all finite orders coprime to the characteristic).

Comment: For the part about denseness: We see from above that the subgroup of elements of finite orders has trivial "complement", so the inclusion of the subgroup gives an isomorphism of the character groups. I think this should give the result, but the final details are escaping me right now.

Comment: Here is the final detail: If the subgroup is not dense, let $H$ be a proper closed subgroup of $G$ containing it and let $\chi$ be a non-trivial character of $G/H$ which then corresponds to a non-trivial character of $G$ with $H$ in the kernel. But by the above, there are no such characters.

Comment: Thanks! I need to think about it.